# Given four edge-lengths of a quadrangle $a,b,c,d$ so that $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$. Prove that $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}<2\left(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd\right).$

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

> Given four edge-lengths of a quadrangle $a, b, c, d$ so that $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$. Prove that
> $$a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}+ d^{2}< 2\left ( ab+ ac+ ad+ bc+ bd+ cd \right )$$

My solution
$$a+ b+ c> d$$
$$\begin{align}\Rightarrow \left ( 2a+ 2b+ 2c \right )d+ \left ( 2a+ 2b \right )c+ 2ab & > 2\left ( a+ b+ c \right )d+ ac+ bc\\
 & > 2d^{2}+ a^{2}+ b^{2}\\
 & \geq c^{2}+ d^{2}+ a^{2}+ b^{2}
\end{align}$$
How about you ?

Comment: OK ! Why do you down-vote me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\Rightarrow 2\left ( ab+ ac+ ad+ bc+ bd+ cd \right ) & = 2\left ( a+ b+ c \right )d+ ab+bc+bc+ca+ca+ab\\
 & \gt 2d^{2}+ \left (c+ a \right)b + \left (a+ b \right)c + \left (b+ c \right)a\\
 & \gt 2d^{2} + b^{2} + \left (a + b \right)c + a^{2} \\
 & \gt c^2 + d^{2} + b^{2} + \left (a + b \right)c + a^{2} \\
& \gt a^2 + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2}
\end{align}